# Error after creating a maven project in Spring STS 3.0

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to follow a tutorial from a site about Spring mvc. And there the very first step was to create a project in Spring STS 3.0.0. I downloaded that and created a project as it described.

But the project structure was not the same and there are some errors also.

`Cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:maven-plugin:2.1.1:runtime Cause: error in opening zip file`

As in the picture the `Maven Dependencies` and `JRE System Library` are missing here. And in the POM.xml there is the above error also.

[image]

The expected project structure is,

[image]

And when I try to `clean install the project it will also failed.

`Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\Intel\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]`

What am I missing here ?

I used `org.apache.maven.archetypes / maven-archetype-webapp / 1.0`

Comment: Regarding the structure, you should configure your classpath (right click to open the properties menu of the project, and add the src/main/resources folder into the sources path). Regarding the pom error, I already had this kind of error while I still could build my project... Not sure it is the blocking problem here

Answer (score 0):

To create a proper Spring MVC project, you need to create new spring template project named as `"Spring MVC project"` which sometimes you need to download it first. You can refer it here :

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-beginner-tutorial-with-spring-tool-suite-ide

If you cannot find the `Spring MVC Project`, click on new project->Spring Legacy Project first then the template will be there. After that the,the template will create the proper Spring MVC Project with proper setup of Maven.